# Why do I get segfault trying to write a value in an array into a CSV file

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

I'm trying to read an 8bit image in binary or raw file format, and put every pixel in a row in a csv file and include the 12 neigbours within 2 pixels in x, y, z. I started by just trying to write the value of each pixel in a

```
// ----------------------- Create pointer to hold input values for ml

    short p[1308*1308*200][13];

    ofstream full_stack;
    full_stack.open("full_stack.csv");
    int index;
    // // ----------------------- for loop execution
    for( int x = 0; x < 1308; x++ ) {
        for( int y = 0; y < 1308; y++ ) {
            for( int z = 0; z < 200; z++ ) {
                index   = x+1308*y+1308*1308*z;

                myData.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
                memcpy(&value, buf, sizeof(buf));   
                p[index][0] =   value;
            }
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1308*1308*200; i++){
        for ( int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
            full_stack << p[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
    full_stack.close();
}
```

Comment: That's an 8+ GB array you declare there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sid_S points out, you're attempting to declare an 8 gigabyte array on the stack. The stack in a typical application on a typical machine these days is around 1-2 megabytes. You need to dynamically allocate the array using `malloc()`, `new`, or by using a C++ collection like `std::vector<short>`. Given that you have a 2-dimensional array, you'd need to do something like `std::vector<std::vector<short>>`.